# cargar variables de sesion de php en javascript - js

Tags: javascript, php

buen dia tengo un JS y necesito cargar una variable de sesión de php en el js para hacer una comparación pero no encontrado la forma para que funcione, estoy dentro de un archivo .js y es ahi es donde necesito utilizar php

```
var datosProducto = new FormData();
        var precio = 0;
        var premium = <? echo $_SESSION['premium'] ?>;
        
        console.log(premium + "variable php");
```

Comment: no puedes accesarlo desde un archivo ".js", el javascript debe correr en el archivo ".php". Algo que puedes hacer es poner la funcion javascript en tu archivo ".js"  y llamar dicha funcion pasandole de parametro la variable de session, desde el ".php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar una variable de PHP a tu JS, el script deberia estar accesible dentro del HTML.

Un caso como el siguiente fallara porque el archivo JS no esta siendo interpretado por PHP directamente

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["premium"] = true; 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Una pagina</title>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Un titulo</h1>    
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

y luego en JS intentarias lo siguiente

```javascript
//JS Script
let premium = <?php echo $_SESSION["premium"] ?>;
console.log(premium);
```

Luego si incluyes el script dentro del HTML del archivo PHP entonces si podrias con PHP hacer la impresion de la variable para que JS la utilice, esto si funcionaria

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["premium"] = true; 
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Una pagina</title>
    <script>
      let premium = <?php echo $_SESSION["premium"] ?>;
      console.log(premium);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Un titulo</h1>    
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Para usar las variables de sesion en PHP la directiva de inicio de sesion debera ir antes de cualquier ejecucion adicional de PHP